# How to make word wrap to literally new line in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, word-wrap

So, for some purpose, im going to put some of my codes in Microsoft Word, but with the limitation of line length in MS Word and difference font size in VS Code and MS Word, i had to adjust everything manually to be in a good format so can easy to read.

I already use the '**word wrap**' setting, spesifically the `wordWrapColumn`'s setting. [image: wordWrapColumn Setting]

Actually that is what i wanted, but when i copy to MS Word, i still have to adjust it manually because the '**word wrap**' setting not put that in literal new line.

[image: Result]

Is there any way to put the '**word wrap**' in literal new line? So i dont have to adjust everything manually in MS Word. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to put the 'word wrap' in literal new line?

There's code formatters that can do that for you, like `clang-format`. You can configure that to whatever line length you want.

Your line, by the way, is simply too long. It's nice that your editor can wrap long lines, but do a right-click on your document and select "format document".

Comment: Thanks the response, but i already use the format document before, with the alt + shift + f too (i just installed clang formatter, but wont work), it just format the document, and i cant change the line length.

Comment: you can put a .clang-format file in your source code tree, and clang format will use the settings from that. There's a maximum line length setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Prettier](https://prettier.io) to format, not only the line wrap, but also other format normalization like tab space.

You can use it in your project via `esbenp.prettier-vscode` extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode). Then, you can set up the **Prettier: Print Width** (`prettier.printWidth`) setting to your desired length (your `wordWrapColumn` value, for example).

You can fine-tune your options for each language if you [create a config file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration) in your project directory. For example, in your `.prettierrc.json` file:

```json
{
  "printWidth": 80,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.js"],
      "options": {
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "printWidth": 100
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check more options in [his documentation page](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options).

> You can install Prettier locally to use an specific Prettier version by installing it via npm: `npm add -D prettier`.

After that, you can format manually your file via `Format document` command, or by enabling *format on save* in settings.